# How to prevent firebase database from creating multiple IDs when using the childByAutoId metod

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to databases and started using the firebase database when I found the childByAutoId function to be useful as it randomly generates an Id code for me. However I have not find a way to prevent duplicate IDs when randomly generating. Is this automatically integrated in method? or is up to me to prevent duplicate Ids from being added into the database and how would do something like this. Thank you.

Comment: So you're saying that you've seen it generate duplicates?

Comment: No I have not seen it generate duplicates but I have not found a source that says that it can either, as far as I know there is a chance it can

Answer (score 1):

The chance of it generating a duplicate is astronomically low. You generally just assume that never generates a dup.  This blog explains in more detail.

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html